# Angularjs ng-repeat sort table with special character ":" in value

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angularjs ng-repeat to sort my records by clicking on table headers, I've found an example who works perfectly, the code are like this:

```
<th ng-repeat="header in headers">
    <a ng-click="toggleSort($index)">{{ headers[$index] }}</a>
</th>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/creed88/u8Ukz/) of this example.

But, my problem is there are index with ":" in my object, and it cause an error like "TypeError: Cannot read property 'col:A' of undefined"

[Here is a demo with ":"](http://jsfiddle.net/creed88/Mu3AY/2/)

So, how can I make it work with ":" ?

Comment: Looks like the same content in both links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug which happens when a special character, such as '%', is used in the OrderBy filter to sort the object by the key.

You can find more details about this issue here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6143

It seems to have been corrected in Angular 1.3.0-beta3.

A workaround is to write your own compare function and to use the [sort() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) of Array.

I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mu3AY/4/) to give you an idea of an compare function and how to use it:

```
function compare(a,b,property) {
  if (a[property] < b[property])
     return -1;
  if (a[property] > b[property])
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the way you call the parameters in the array:

```
$scope.headers = ['sortColumn', 'colB'];
$scope.records = [{sortColumn: 'a1', colB: 'd1'}, {sortColumn: 'c2', colB: 'b2'}, {sortColumn: 'b3', colB: 'c3'}, {sortColumn: 'd4', colB: 'a4'}];

$scope.sortColumn = 'colA';
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mu3AY/3/)